# How to show image in Footer for pdf report using DynamicJasper API?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I am developing a *pdf* report using *DynamicJasper API*.

As per requirement I have to display one logo at header and other at footer. I am able to display logo at header by using **DynamicReportBuilder.addImageBanner** method. But i didn't find a way to add an image at footer.

I saw some threads regarding this issue in dynamic-jasper forum , the one work around which mentioned there is to create a *jrxml* template with *pageFooter* band.

I tried this, but didn't work out. I got following exception:

`org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed`

Following is the code which generate report.

1. Creating a *dynamiceReport* object
2. Creating a *jasperPrint* object
3. Invoking a method which create report based on the format type. Here i have to pass *jasperPrint* object, which has *jrxml* representation, target file location and report format type.

```java
// ...
    DynamicReport dynamicReport = buildDynamicReport(reportTemplate, grpFields);

    // build jrxml <br/>
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = buildJRXML(dynamicReport, dataSource, reportFormat);

    // export the report into specific target format <br/>
    exportReport(jasperPrint, targetReportFile, reportFormat);
// ...

private DynamicReport buildDynamicReport(Template reportTemplate,
                                         Vector<String[]> groupFields) throws ServiceException {
    /** code to generate DynamicReport object. */
    dynamicReportBuilder.setTemplateFile("jrxml/report-footer.jrxml");
    DynamicReport dynamicReport = dynamicReportBuilder.build();

    return dynamicReport;
}
```

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the dynamicjasper's ClassicLayoutManager class applies all image banners to only header band by default, there does not seem to be a straight forward way of achieving this.

One workaround is to use a custom layout manager implementation - extending ClassicLayoutManager and overriding the applyBanners() method.

```
public class CustomLayoutManager extends ClassicLayoutManager {

    protected void applyBanners() {
        super.applyBanners(); //let the ClassicLayoutManager apply header banners

        // explicitly add banner to footer band..
        JRDesignBand pageFooter = (JRDesignBand)getDesign().getPageFooter();

        // if there is no footer band we create one
        if(pageFooter == null) {
            pageFooter = new JRDesignBand();
            getDesign().setPageFooter(pageFooter);
        }

        Vector<ImageBanner> vImageBanner = new Vector<ImageBanner>();
        vImageBanner.add(new ImageBanner("yourlogoimage.ext", 120, 50, ImageBanner.ALIGN_LEFT));

        applyImageBannersToBand(pageFooter, vImageBanner, null);
    }
}
```

and then use the custom class in while generating the report..

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperPrint(dynamicReport, new CustomLayoutManager(), parameters);
```